# Use Python to send keystrokes to Gameboy emulator in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sendkeys

This question was asked 3 years ago and the guy ended up with unsatisfying results.

See: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/22tke1/use_python_to_send_keystrokes_to_games_in_windows/

Also posted on this site (w/ less discussion):
[Use Python to send keystrokes to games in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024525/use-python-to-send-keystrokes-to-games-in-windows)

My issue is the exact same as his was: My scripts can send keystrokes to everything (web browser, text doc, shell, etc.) except to a game window. Specifically it's a Gameboy Color Emulator named `bgb` that I'm using to play Pokemon Blue. I just want my code to be able to play the game.

I have tried the `shell.SendKeys`, `api.keybd_event`, and `ctypes` methods shown in the code in the links above. I've also tried `pyautogui`. All of these work to interact with most programs, just not the Emulator.

I even had the silly idea to use Windows On-Screen Keyboard and send mouse clicks to the coordinates of relevant buttons. While the mouse clicks worked on other applications, it would not actually click the On-Screen Keyboard.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can remote control BGB over TCP/IP.

Here are some examples:

- https://github.com/digital-pet/pybgblink
- https://github.com/vaguilar/pokemon-red-cable-club-hack

BGB Link protocol documentation:
https://bgb.bircd.org/bgblink.html

> ## 101 - joypad
>
> Joypad change, for remote control of an emulator. The receiving end
> can choose to ignore joypad changes, or update its button state
> accordingly.
>
> Any bits and fields other than the ones used for a purpose MUST be 0
> when sending, and MUST be ignored when receiving.
>
> ```
> b2=joypad change
>   bit 0-2: button number
>   bit 3: 1 if button is pressed, 0 if button is released
>   bit 4-7: 0 (due to a bug in previous bgb versions, these bits can't be used in the future and must remain 0)
> b3=0
> b4=0
> i1=0
> ```