# Python SendInput() keypress doesn't get recognised

Tags: python, windows, winapi, keyboard, simulate

I tried to simulate keypresses in python, but they dont get recognised the programm. All work in simple editors, some even in an open admin cmd window, but nothing here.

What I tried so far:
-librarys: pyautogui, keyboard, pydirectinput, pynput, pyKey

Solutions with ctypes and SendInput:

- [Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown/11910555)
- [Use Python to send keystrokes to games in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024525/use-python-to-send-keystrokes-to-games-in-windows)
- [Simulating a keypress in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489149/simulating-a-keypress-in-python)

All other solutions i found were all using win32api or SendInput and didn't work either.
The usecase is the programm Parsec, if that helps. Also mouse movement and clicks work fine with all of the solutions above.

Could anyone help me with that, or point me in a direction? Because i don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs, especially video games, are specifically made to be resistant to what you are trying to do. This is to prevent bots and cheating within the game or program. You could find a way to make a driver that simulates key presses, but considering that the program has taken specific measures to defend against this, it is likely bannable or violates the Terms and Service agreement.

Comment: I use it as a remote Desktop stream, and i doubt that it's something against their tos, or that they ever ban anyone from using their program.